# Mongod command shows error on Fedora33 OS

Tags: mongodb, fedora-33

I'm struggling to get mongoDB to work on Fedora33.
I already disabled SELinux.

When I run $mongo, it works:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("8a6f3184-dc10-4fe8-be0a-5532a421d0ea") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.5
```

but when i run $mongod i get this error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-12T00:40:51.031-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-12T00:40:51.033-04:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-12T00:40:51.033-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-12T00:40:51.034-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":4184,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"hive"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-12T00:40:51.034-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.5","gitVersion":"ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"rhel70","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-12T00:40:51.034-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Fedora release 33 (Thirty Three)","version":"Kernel 5.11.11-200.fc33.x86_64"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-12T00:40:51.034-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-12T00:40:51.035-04:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-12T00:40:51.035-04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-12T00:40:51.035-04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Already tried using a different port, get similar errors.
Created folders based on mongo config file.
Thanks for giving this a look.

Comment: Who is the owner of path `/data/db`?

Comment: When run only `mongod`, i.e. without `-f / --config` option, then it uses default values (see [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/)) but not your config file.

Comment: Can you find these documents helpful? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-transport-encryption/

Comment: Who is the owner of path /data/db?
I created a /data/db using the login user.

I tried both `mongod` and also changing the port option, but result in similar errors. 

I did come across these does Avaini, but I initially dismissed these as the problem didn't seem to be SSL related. I will take a closer look.